# Insert value in DB with form on a barcode scanner

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms, barcode-scanner

I have a Datalogic Barcode Scanner Falcon 4410. I have a html form on it to add products into a database.
Here is my simple form :

```
<form id="formprod" class="form-horizontal" method="post" action="url">
    <fieldset>
    <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="col-md-4 control-label" for="textinput">Référence</label>  
      <div class="col-md-4">
      <input id="textinput" name="reference" type="text" placeholder="placeholder" class="form-control input-md">
      </div>
    </div>

    <!-- Button (Double) -->
    <div class="form-group">
      <div class="col-md-8">
        <input type="submit" id="button1id" name="submit" value="OK" class="btn btn-success"/>
        <input type="reset" id="button2id" name="button2id" value="RESET" class="btn btn-danger"/>
      </div>
    </div>

    </fieldset>
</form>
```

So, in the barcode scanner if I open my html page, write with virtual keyboard in input and submit with submit button: it works. 
But if I'm scanning a barcode, form is automatically submitted, record is saved but reference field is empty in DB.
My PHP code :

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["reference"])){
    $hostname='****';
    $username='****';
    $password='*****';

    try {
        $dbh = new PDO("mysql:host=$hostname;dbname=name",$username,$password);

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $sql = "INSERT INTO product (reference)
        VALUES ('".$_POST["reference"]."')";
        if ($dbh->query($sql)) {
        echo 'Done!';
        }
        else{
        echo 'Error!';
        }

        $dbh = null;
    }
    catch(PDOException $e)
    {
        echo $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Do you have an idea?
Thanks.

PS : It's not optimized for SQL injection for example, it will be done when record will work

**EDIT : WORK AFTER A REBOOT.**

Comment: That looks like a sql injection waiting to happen.

Comment: It's not optimized, it will be done when record will work... Thanks.

Comment: Have you checked if $_POST["reference"]) contains a value? Try to echo the value out on the 1st line in your try and see if it contains a value.

Comment: Is the . between between the strings and your variable really necessary? Does it not work without them? EG: "INSERT INTO product (reference) VALUES ('"$_POST["reference"]"')"

Comment: I added `if(empty($_POST["reference"]){echo 'empty';}else...` and variable is empty. And it's not empty if I write it with keyboard

Comment: I did a reboot on barcode scanner and it works... Thanks for your time.

Comment: You should really be careful when writing code like this. Even if you have plans to make it "sql injection save" later on, usually something comes inbetween or you forget about that part and things like this don't get fixed until you have an issue.

Comment: Ok thank you for your advice, I'm going to resolve it now.

Answer (score 0):

Most barcode scanners I've used in libraries send a carriage return following the data they've scanned.  There is often a way to declare that you don't want a CR in the scanner's settings.  Check the manufacturer's website.